# PHP MySQL insert data from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from one table to another, i have took references from many sites and Stackoverflow but I wasn't able to solve  error. 
The last field is the applicant field where I would like to send Default value 'No'.
I want to do this whole thing in single query

```
insert into user_identity (login_no, customer_id, prename, 
fullname, mobile, dob, age, applicant) values
select login_id, customer_id, c_prename, CONCAT_WS(' ',`c_firstname`,`c_lastname`),
 c_mobile, dob, age, 'No' from customer where id = '1'
```

Comment: Could you tell us how the two tables are set-up?

Comment: What is `applicant` likely to contain in the customer table ? If you want to replace NULLs with No just use COALESCE(applicant,'No')

Comment: what more information do you want? @Xavjer

Comment: No @Giles I want send value 'No' to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the keyword VALUES is not needed,try this..

```
insert into user_identity (login_no, customer_id, prename, 
fullname, mobile, dob, age, applicant) 
select login_id, customer_id, c_prename, CONCAT_WS(' ',c_firstname,c_lastname),
 c_mobile, dob, age, 'No' from customer where id = '1'
```

refer this.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I think you want in the fullname field the actual first/lastname concatinated, therefore you will have to remove the ` making it look like this: CONCAT_WS(' ',c_firstname,c_lastname),

Answer (score 0):

When we are inserting from another table, we do not use the keyword values as we are not providing the values implicitly. we are fetching it from another table. 
So in that sense, to create a table as an exact replica of another we can do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE EMP as SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Similarly while inserting we do something like this

```
Insert into <tablename>(column name) select (column name) from <Table name>
```